# Are review questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Consider the following: Someone has written an algorithm (or came up with some math in general). Are questions about possible improvements (eg. simplification) on topic for this forum?

Analogy: For the programmers out there, there is a codereview-stackexchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question can be seen as falling under [proof-verification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-verification), whose tag-wiki also mentions improvements; possibly [proof-writing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-writing) is also relevant. It can thus be considered as in principle on-topic.

However, it is important to make sure that the question is not "too broad" or too big a demand. If the proof is a few paragraphs long, this can be a reasonable question; if you link to a twenty page pdf somewhere, this might not go over so well.

Moreover, try to be as specific as possible regarding what type of improvements you are looking for.